# Inequality with two unknowns and two real parameters

Tags: inequality

I have a problem with next inequality: $ (x_1 - x_2)^2 + (a - 1)x_1^2 + (b - 1)x_2^2 \ge 0, (x_1, x_2, a, b \in \Bbb{R}) $. I really don't know what should i do with it. I don't have any steps to show and i'm stuck at the beginning. Any kind of help is the most welcome! Thank you for your time!

Comment: any information you could provide about $a,b,x_1,x_2$ ?

Comment: I made a correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \ge 1 $ and $b \ge 1$ we have

$(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (a - 1)x_1^2 + (b - 1)x_2^2 \ge 0$

since $(x_1 - x_2)^2 \ge 0$, $(a - 1)x_1^2  \ge 0 $ and $(b - 1)x_2^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: What is not true ?? I wrote "if $a \ge 1 ....$. Nobody said that if $a<1....$ that then $(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (a - 1)x_1^2 + (b - 1)x_2^2 < 0$. It has many advantages, if you read exactly..... So, why the downvote ?

Comment: Maybe you made a typo? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Where I made a typo ?

Comment: Well, if you didn't i to don't understand why he said it's not correct.

Comment: What's the matter ? I said $(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (a - 1)x_1^2 + (b - 1)x_2^2 \ge 0$ if $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$. That is true !

Comment: I don't know why he said that it's not true! Thank you for help!